# Unable to validate XML against XSD schema

Tags: python, xml, xsd, lxml

I am working on a Python project where we have a function generating an XML Schema from data gathered from different sources. The main objective is not to validate the output of this function using an authoritative schema (namely https://github.com/ietf-tools/xml2rfc/blob/main/xml2rfc/data/v3.rnc).

The official authoritative schema is in Relax NG Compact (RNC) format. Thus, I converted this schema into an XSD schema using the [trang](https://relaxng.org/jclark/trang.html) official converter tool.

[Here is the XSD Schema](https://gist.github.com/stefanomunarini/952f676f4e7e967295d35c430cf059d5).

During conversion of the schema, the following warning message is shown:

```
xml2rfc/xml2rfc/data/v3.rnc:495:45: warning: cannot represent an optional group of attributes; approximating
```

Now, I used an [online validator](https://www.utilities-online.info/xsdvalidation) to validate the XSD obtained using trang, which confirms that XSD is syntactically correct.

If, however, using the same tool I try to validate an XML file, the following error messages are raised:

```
- Element '{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}attributeGroup', attribute 'ref': The QName value '{http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace}base' does not resolve to a(n) attribute group definition.

- Element '{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}attributeGroup', attribute 'ref': The QName value '{http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace}lang' does not resolve to a(n) attribute group definition.

- Element '{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}element', attribute 'ref': The QName value '{http://www.w3.org/2000/svg}svg' does not resolve to a(n) element declaration.
```

Same thing happens when I try to parse the XSD schema using the [lxml](https://lxml.de) python library.

Does anyone have any idea how these issues can be addressed?

Comment: Where is it loaded from `failed to load external entity "xlink.xsd"`, your question should be a [minimum verifiable example](/help/mcve).

Comment: Presumably the schema documents (for XLink, etc) referenced in `xs:import` statements are not present at the locations identified.